# Managed Navigation doesn't show page link as selected

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata, managed-navigation, metadata-navigation

I'm going to start off by saying that I have inherited this Managed Navigation Term Store. I didn't build it and I know only enough to create new terms and add Navigation values to point to the correct page/URL.

The problem I have is that when I go to a list/library and change the view, all of a sudden the page listed in the Left Navigation Bar no longer appears selected. It used to always default to showing the Home page as selected, but I fixed that when I noticed that the Simple Link for Home and the Associated Folder were just `"/"` and encompassed everything.

To give an example of what is currently set up, there is a list called Employees on the main site. So the Simple Link or Header points to `/Lists/Employees/AllItems.aspx` and the Associated Folder points to `/Lists/Employees/`

This works fine and when I click on the Employees link in the navigation menu, the link shows as selected. When I change the view to "`Show by department`" the Employees link no longer appears selected in the navigation menu (nothing shows as selected).

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth checking the hidden list "`TaxonomyHiddenList`" to see if the permissions are correct. I have witnessed similar issues in viewing terms from the termstore just because this hidden list's permissions were set to "Unique" and had no permissions set. When this happens, very odd things happen where terms are concerned.

Go to the **hidden** list :

```
[site with issue url]/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx
```

Then go to the list settings, and check the permissions just like you would with a normal list.

If you find that the permissions are blank, you need to ensure that **all authenticated users** have **read** permissions.

Please note, you need to be a site collection administrator to do this with this list.

This list is one of the many hidden SharePoint lists. There is no link to take you to this list, so you need to know the URL.